# Generating random variables from standard uniform distribution on $(1,0)$

Tags: probability, statistics

A random number generator generates random values from the standard uniform distribution $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. Call this random variable $U$. Starting with a random value $u$ from $U$, show all the steps necessary to generate a random variable $X$ such that the probability mass function $p(x)$ of $X$ is:

$p(1)=0.3$

$p(2)=0.15$

$p(3)=0.35$

$p(4)=0.2$

I'm not looking for an exact answer as much as an explanation to help with these problems in the future.

Comment: Try partioning $[0,1]$ into disjoint parts with lengths given by your probabilities using the fact that $P(a\leq U\leq b)=b-a$ when $a<b$ and $a,b\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your random number generator will produce (pseudo) random numbers uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

Suppose that we want to simulate a random variable $X$ which takes on value $3$ with probability $0.25$, value $7$ with probability $0.35$, and value $45.6$ with probability $0.40$ (of course, this is not your problem, just a similar one).

Use the following idea. If the random number generator produces a number between $0$ and $0.25$, report that $X$ has taken on value $3$.

If the random number generator produces a number between $0.25$ and $0.25+0.35$, that is, between $0.25$ and $0.60$, report that $X$ has taken on the value $7$.

Finally, if the random number generator produces a number between $0.25+0.35$ and $1$, report that $X$ has taken on the value $45.6$.

Note that the probability that the random number generator produces a number between $0$ and $0.25$ is $0.25$. So with probability $0.25$ we will be reporting that $X$ has taken on value $3$. The probability that the random number generator produces a number between $0.25$ and $0.25+0.35$ is $0.35$, so with probability $0.35$ we will be reporting that $X$ has taken on value $17$. And so on.

**Remarks:** 1) In principle, the random number generator produces "random" reals between $0$ and $1$. So the probability it produces a particular number $u$, like $1/\pi$, is $0$. In practice, the numbers produced are say decimals, to $10$ decimal places. So our program needs to deal with the highly improbable but possible situations where the random number produced is *exactly* at a boundary, like $0.25$. It doesn't really matter what we do.

2) The procedure we use can also be described in terms of the **cumulative distribution function** of the random variable we are trying to simulate. Perhaps you are expected to do it in that style, in preparation for more complex problems when we are simulating a continuously distributed random variable $X$. If a description in terms of the cdf is required, please indicate.